# How to combine reducers and divide them into own files in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have very simple App. This is the counter app where buttons are images and every image has its own counter.
[image: Counter app]

I have imported the reducer of the counters to my **App.js** file `import reducer from './reducers/reducerCounter';`

I have created a store for the reducer `const store = createStore(reducer);`

I have also set the default values of counter inside the reducer(in separate file)

```
const reducerCounter = (state={counterBarca:0,counterReal:0}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT_BARCA':
      return { ...state, counterBarca: state.counterBarca + 1 };
    case 'INCREMENT_REAL':
      return { ...state, counterReal: state.counterReal + 1 };
    default:
      return state;
    }
};

export default reducerCounter;
```

Everything works fine but now I'd like to create another reducer and combine them using combineReducers in separate file called index.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import reducerAnother from './reducerAnother'
import reducerCounter from './reducerCounter'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({reducerCounter, reducerAnother});

export default rootReducer;
```

It does not even display the default value of the counters. There is no error or warnings in console. I import my new file with combine reducers like this

```
import reducer from './reducers/index';
```

Here is my Counter component file where the counters and the images are displayed. This component also makes one image bigger onclick(and the second image smaller at the same time)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import barca_logo from '../barca.png';
import real_logo from '../real.png';

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      barca_logo_height: 200,
      real_logo_height: 200
    }

  }

  render() {
    const { counterBarca, counterReal, onIncrementBarca, onIncrementReal } = this.props;

    const incClickBarca = () => {
      onIncrementBarca();
      increaseSizeBarca();
    };
    const incClickReal = () => {
      onIncrementReal();
      increaseSizeReal();
    };

    const increaseSizeBarca = () => {
      if (counterBarca < 30) {
        this.setState({
          barca_logo_height: this.state.barca_logo_height + (this.state.barca_logo_height/50),
          real_logo_height: this.state.real_logo_height - (this.state.real_logo_height/50)
        });
      }
    }

    const increaseSizeReal = () => {
      if (counterReal < 30) {
        this.setState({
          real_logo_height: this.state.real_logo_height + (this.state.real_logo_height/50),
          barca_logo_height: this.state.barca_logo_height - (this.state.barca_logo_height/50)
        });        
      }
    }
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-5">
            <img className="teamLogo" height={this.state.barca_logo_height} src={barca_logo} onClick={() => incClickBarca()} alt="team"/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-2">
            <span>{counterBarca}</span>
            <span> : </span>
            <span>{counterReal}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-4">
            <img className="teamLogo" height={this.state.real_logo_height} src={real_logo} onClick={() => incClickReal()} alt="team"/>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    counterBarca: state.counterBarca,
    counterReal: state.counterReal,
   };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onIncrementBarca: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_BARCA' }),
    onIncrementReal: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_REAL' })
  }
};

Counter = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);

export default Counter;
```

Why it did not even display the default value of the counters when I have all components, reducers and while app in separate files ?

I saw that when I type   `console.log(state);` inside **reducerCounter** file I see that it is working but the numbers from the counter are still not displayed

[image: state logs]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to export as rootReducer, instead use this under reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import reducerAnother from './reducerAnother'
import reducerCounter from './reducerCounter'

export default combineReducers({
  reducerAnother,
  reducerCounter
})
```

Then import it like:

```
import rootReducer from './reducers'
```

Comment: unfortunately the same behavior. My counters are `undefined` when I `console.log` them inside the Counter component file.

Comment: Apologies for replying late. I need to check the code, can you host it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)`

or use **other name** for connected component

```
const ConnectedCounter = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);

export default ConnectedCounter;
```